# good c++ editor

Tags: c++, text-editor

I'm going to teach teenagers some C++ code. I need an editor which is simple and has built in compiler. We tried CodeBlocks but when we installed it in the machines, the text got reversed, I'm not sure what the reaoson is. I would be great if the file size of the editor will not be large.

We need just simple features:

**-Text highlight.**

**-Compile and run.**

**-easy to  use**

**-Should run on Windows XP.**

Comment: You should ask questions on programming tools on Stack Overflow, not Programmers. Please read our [FAQ] thoroughly to see what questions we welcome here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Dev C++`.

- Dev-C++ is an full-featured Integrated Development Environment (IDE) for Win32. It uses GCC, Mingw or Cygwin as compiler and libraries set.
- You can find this superseded by http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/.
- It is also licensed as *GNU General Public License version 3.0*.
- Includes MinGW GCC 4.6.2 32bit.
- Includes TDM-GCC 4.6.1 64bit.
- Provides syntax highlighting for code, header and resource files.
- Supports code completion and autocomplete.
- Shows information about code when hovering above code.
- Supports GPROF profiling.
- Provides user-editable shortcuts and tools.
- Supports multiple languages.
- Supports GNU GDB debugging.
- Supports code folding.
- Supports devpak IDE extensions.

Comment: Will that run on Windows XP?

Comment: @romani Yes, of course.